# How to deal with compositional data by using NMF (scikit-learn)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, nmf

I have a compositional data matrix V, whose i-th row is the element ratio of the i-th sample. Finding a matrix decomposition as follows:

[image]

How can i solve this question use Non-negative matrix factorization (NMF or NNMF)?

Comment: Your image link is incorrect or broken.

Comment: I can open it. Image link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WjL0.png

Comment: With sklearn's NMF? You can't. This should be clear after reading their objective function.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How should I do? Is there a Python model to deal with it?

Comment: Not that i know of. You probably have to build your own optimizer (probably based on alternative minimization with projections).

Comment: On a second look the projection looks non-trivial (not sure if valuable to pursue). Look up anything you can find on *constrained* nmf (in vector-terms the projection would be one to the probability-simplex; but in your case it's more complex as those are matrices).

Comment: i read the paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016794739800098X

Comment: I think it would help me solve this question, but i still have no ideas about the paper. so sad.